# kohana 3: How to create a route for a backend part?

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3

I have created a "backend" folder in /application/classes/controller/ in a kohana 3.2 application.

So I have a folder structure like:

```
/application
+/classes
++/controller/
+++/A_controller.php
+++/Another_controller.php
+++/backend/
++++/A_Backend_controller.php
```

The routes in my bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('backend', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'backend',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

I have an .htaccess that rewrites my URLs and remove the "index.php" from the url, so that I usually call a page like this:
www.mysite.com/controller_name/action_name

From what I read in the route documentation, with the "backend" route I wrote, this should work:
www.mysite.com/backend/controller_name/action_name

But it doesnt... any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have `<directory>` in your route. This will change the directory value when Kohana tries to load your route.  Your backend route should look like this.

```
Route::set('backend', 'backend(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'backend',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Note: This route has to come before your default catch-all route.  Otherwise Kohana will never get to your route.

Comment: nope, I also tried this and it didn't solve anything. <directory> in the route::set will just be replaced by the 'directory' value from the defaults array...

Comment: @Piero My guess is you have deviated from Kohana's class naming structure which would cause Kohana's routing to fail.  Can you give an example of a route, the class it should map to and the location of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You define two routes, and do not 'overload' the regex for any segment. The default regex for a segment is `[^/.,;?\n]++` so every segment has to match to that regex.

Your first route is the route that comes with Kohana out of the box. It will match 0, 1, 2 and 3 segments separated by a slash.
Your second route will match 1, 2, 3 and 4 segments.

Since you add them in that order the route named 'default' will only fail to match for more then three segements like this uri: user/purcheses/view/42. When the route 'default' fails to match the uri the next route will be checked. In your case the route named 'backend'.

If you swap the order of the two routes, then the route 'backend' will be first and will only fail for 0 or more then 4 segments. With 0 segments the route 'default' will match it and with 5 or more segments a Http_Exception_404 will be thrown.
But when you place the 'backend' first it will only route to controllers in subdirectories which most likely breaks a lot of pages.

You could replace the `<directory>` by a hardcoded value, add a regex for the  or create a lambda/callback route.

In order:

```
Route::set('backend', 'backend(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'backend',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('backend', '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('foo|bar|backend'))
->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'backend',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

// not tested
Route::set('nested', function($uri, $directory = '')
{
    if ( ! $segments = explode('/', $uri))
        return;

    // get a multidimensional array of the Cascading File System with classes/controller as the root
    $list = Kohana::list_files('classes/controller');

    foreach($segments AS $segment)
    {
        if ( ! isset($list['classes/controller/'.$directory.$segment]))
            break;

        // we found a new existing directory, append it
        $directory .= array_shift($segments).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        // reduce $list to the remaining possible paths
        $list = $list[rtrim('classes/controller/'.$directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)];
    }

    if ( ! empty($directory) AND $params = Route::get('default')->matches(implode('/', $segments)))
    {
        $params['directory'] = rtrim($directory, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

        return $params;
    }
},
    // this is used for reverse routing
    '<directory>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'dashboard',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Comment: I understand your approach, but your function is a bit unclear at the end, in the last if condition. I understand the search into the the controllers folder etc, but why would I have to do that? Kohana is suppose to have a powerful routing system, easy to configure, this looks like a hack to me.

Comment: If $directory is empty, the first segments do not reflect folders. Since the reverse routing route contains a non-optional <directory> we wat to say it does not match this route. If it does reflect folders, match the remaining uri (notice the array_shift()) with the 'default' route. If that is a match add the directory to the parameters and return. You should give that route the same defaults as the 'default' route. Remember this just an example of how you could implement it. This route should also route user/repository/admin/dashboard to classes/controller/user/repository/admin/dashboard.php

Answer (score 1):

As said Wade your route backend has to come before your default route.

Then check that you have a home.php in your backend folder with a controller defined as follow:

```
class Controller_Backend_Home extends Controller {
    public function action_index(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I am using in one of my application

```
Route::set('default', 'admin/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'admin',
            'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Route::set('user', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

How it will work?

- According to `Kohana`, a route listed first, gets the highest priority.
- If it can't find any match for any route it fall back to `default` route

First thing is, if we wanna work with directory structure, we need to put those directory based route listed first. If you take a look, if we were supposed to put the `user` route listed first, it will be selected for any url pattern like: `http://example.com/directory/controller/action`.

To avoid such a scenario, we need to list those kind of route after `directory based` route. Yes it is weird. But this is how it works for kohana. I wish Kohana will improve this behavior.

**Update** Try debugging with [Lambda/Callback route logic](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic). It might explain everything.

```
Route::set('testing', function($uri)
{
    if ($uri == 'foo/bar') // check the prefix for "backend"
        return array(
            'controller' => 'welcome',
            'action'     => 'foobar',
        );
    },
    'foo/bar'
);
```

Comment: Actually I tried this already and it didn't work... I moved it up and down and renamed and changed the conf but nothing did it... I think it's an .htaccess related problem... but still can't solve it... thanks for your help anyway! :)

Comment: When no route matches a Http_Eception_404 will be thrown. There is nothing special about a route named 'default'. It is there as an example and to give a 'hello world' response after you remove install.php.

Comment: have you tried? http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic